# ngResource can't access "@magid" causing "has no method push"

Tags: angularjs

`TypeError: Object #<g> has no method 'push'`

I found this is the single most annoying debugging information angularJS could ever give to me: you just simple don't know what it is! And based on my research, people encounter them in very different situations!

Basically this is my ngResource factory:

```
  .factory('Articles', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('http://localhost/../api/articles/:id', {
      id : '@magid',  //pass in param (magId) //or get from data object
    });
  })
```

Normally when I call this, I use query method to get all articles: `$scope.curMagArticles = Articles.query({id:curMagId});` Like this, it's simple and easy (and it works).

Then later on I find out that I need to save them as well.

I tried this:

```
 var magArray = $scope.curMagArticles;
 magArray['id'] = magArray[0].magazineID;
 Articles.save(magArray);
```

Actually I first tried `magArray.$save()`, theorically shouldn't this work? (Since $scope.curMagArticles is an ngResource object, it should contain `$save()` method right? But console error tells me it doesn't have `$save()`f method) By the way, the code above is how I got `$curMagArticles` (through `Articles.query()`).

I don't know what's causing my problem and my guess is `id:'@magid'` can't get data. Btw I also tried `magArray['magid']`; it didn't work either.

What should I do???

---

Btw this is the `magArray` in console after I add "id" to it:

```
Array[4]
0: g
1: g
2: g
3: g
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
id: "7"
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: The save method would be available on each item like, `magArray[0].$save()`

Comment: @Chandermani WOW! You are absolutely right! But `Articles` get an array instead of one object from backend api, you would think you should send all arrays back as a whole right?

Comment: Wouldn't it be very inefficient if I send back each articles every time?

Comment: Would it be more efficient to simply get all of the articles in one go and then store them in a variable for local access? Obviously depends on how many articles you are talking about but it might be more efficient.